# Error: truncated incorrect integer value for 1.245.634

Tags: mysql

I have this data

```
Text_table
1.245.634
2.795.734
14.235.636
1.242.830
17.397.634
16.285.634
```

This table type es `text`. I want to change this table type to `int`.
I tried to change the column type in `column properties`: `varchar(50)` to `int`. but I have this error:

`Error:  truncated incorrect integer value for 1.245.634`

I also use `cast(Table_text as int)`, but I have numbers like this (the first decimal to the point):

```
Text_table
1
2
14
1
17
16
```

I also use `cast(Text_table as decimal)`, but it add a comma and delete other numbers.

Im trying to get the same table as `int` type without losing numbers and without changing commas for points

Comment: You can't convert it. Integers don't have `.` or `,` in them - they only have digits (`1234567890`) and sign characters (`+-`). I'm guessing that the `.` in your values represent the thousands separator; you'll have to remove it before you can convert or cast the contents to an integer. You should never store formatting characters - add them when needed for presentation purposes.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite! I used `cast( Replace (Text_table, '.' , '') as int)` and it works!

Comment: Yeah Decimal is NOT an Integer but looks like Ken got you.   What is strange is why there are 2 sets of decimals in the number?  In the UK they sometimes do that instead of a comma, so if you are intending to convert 1,245,634 into just a single 1 .. then you are on the right track.  Granted maybe it is not this, but just pointing it out for others to take note.

Answer (score -1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/number-literals.html says:

> Integers are represented as a sequence of digits. Numbers may include . as a decimal separator. Numbers may be preceded by - or + to indicate a negative or positive value, respectively.

There are no thousands separators in MySQL numeric literals.

MySQL has a function [FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) that adds thousands separators to an integer or scaled numeric value, but these are not stored.

There is no builtin function that removes a string of digits with thousands separators to a numeric value. In the comments above, you did it with the string function REPLACE() and then CAST() that resulting string to an integer, but this is more like string manipulation.